# Foldr for nested lists

Tags: nested, scheme, racket, nested-lists, fold

### Problem

Ok, so we all know about foldr and how it works on lists. But what about a foldr that works on nested lists? This is the problem that I'm tackling today, building a function called nested-foldr that takes in the same parameters as foldr but works with nested lists as well.

### Example

Since the nested lists can have as many lists inside them, here is an example

```
(nested-foldr + 0 (list 1 (list 5 5 (list 1 3)) (list 10 2) 2))
```

This should return 29.

### Current Solution

I haven't gotten much down yet. I made a function called my-foldr, which basically does what foldr does. "combine" is the function that is applied to the list, "base" is the base case. "lst" is the list that the function consumes.

```
(define (my-foldr combine base lst)
  (cond [(empty? lst) base]
        [else (combine (first lst) (my-foldr combine base (rest lst)))]))
```

Edit: I've thought a bit more about it and the use of the "`member?`" predicate should be useful here too. Though I am not sure how I can use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution isn't taking into consideration that any element in the list can be a list itself, and we need to recur over it - in fact, we're dealing with *trees*, not just lists. It's trickier than it seems, and I can't think of a way to preserve `foldr` order without first reversing the input. Nevertheless, this worked for me:

```
(define (reverse-tree tree)
  (let loop ((lst tree)
             (acc '()))
    (cond ((null? lst) acc)
          ((not (pair? lst)) lst)
          (else (loop (cdr lst)
                      (cons (car lst)
                            acc))))))

(define (nested-foldr combine base tree)
  (let loop ((lst (reverse-tree tree))
             (acc base))
    (cond ((null? lst) acc)
          ((not (pair? lst)) lst)
          (else (loop (cdr lst)
                      (combine (nested-foldr combine base (car lst))
                               acc))))))
```

For example:

```
(nested-foldr + 0 '(1 (5 5 (1 3)) (10 2) 2))
=> 29
(nested-foldr cons '() '(1 (5 5 (1 3)) (10 2) 2))
=> '(1 (5 5 (1 3)) (10 2) 2)
```

Comment: Thank you. This was really useful! Would there be a way to do this without using loop though? I will accept this answer soon if no one else answers. I also want to look at what other people have to say :)

Comment: It's not a loop-loop :) . It's a [named `let`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/let.html#%28part._.Named_let%29): a convenient way to define a helper procedure. I named it "loop" for clarity, but you can use any other name. If it's confusing, you can define it as an external helper procedure. The important thing to understand is that it's just a normal, recursive procedure - nothing fancy, not a "loop" statement in the sense of other programming languages.

Comment: Sorry for misreading it, my bad. Since I am a beginner I am very unfamiliar with the different things in Racket. Would it be possible to do it without "let"?

Comment: Sure, just copy the contents of the "named let" into a new procedure, and make sure to pass the correct parameters and call it with the correct values. Remember, it's just a normal procedure with simplified syntax.

Comment: Thank you! I will make sure to look into the syntax of let.

Comment: I think it is fairly simple to do this without reversing the tree, depending what one means by "nested foldr". Your solution treats each subtree as a new foldr argument, starting over from the initializer. That's one reasonable interpretation, but a simpler approach also consistent with the (again, ambiguous) question would be to fold up only the non-list elements, effectively implementing `(foldr f init (flatten xs))`. Alternatively, even with the specification you chose, I think it's easy to avoid reversing if you don't try to keep an `acc` parameter: it's not tail-recursive anyway.

Comment: Accepted! It seems like no one else wanted to try this question. It is very challenging. I'm a bit confused by the `(let loop ((lst (reverse-tree tree))
             (acc base))` in the nested-foldr. Could you explain a bit? I'm not very good at Scheme.

Answer (score 0):

Your elements might be atomic, or they might be lists in need of folding themselves. Thus we turn your

```
(define (my-foldr g z lst)
  (cond
    [(empty? lst) z]
    [else (g (first lst) 
             (my-foldr g z (rest lst)))]))
```

into

```
(define (nested-foldr g z lst)
  (cond
    [(empty? lst) z]
    [(not (pair? (first lst))) ; atomic? (first lst)
       (g (first lst)
          (nested-foldr g z (rest lst)))]
    [else 
       (nested-foldr g 
          (nested-foldr g z (rest lst))
          (first lst))]))
```

This starts folding on the right, just like the list-based `foldr` does, and uses the calculated value to continue folding on the left if that's non-atomic, or just combines with the `first` value, if it *is* atomic.

Indeed,

```
(nested-foldr + 0 (list 1 (list 5 5 (list 1 3)) (list 10 2) 2))

29
```